# How to return Observable from subscribe or map?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java

I want to return Observable in the Subscribe function , but I read the document that it is impossible.
So I tried to this by using map function. However, it generated the error.

This is the code:

```
interface DataSource {

    fun getItem() : Observable<List<RetroCrypto>>
}
```

//

```
object RemoteDataSource : DataSource {

private val myCompositeDisposable by lazy { CompositeDisposable() }

override fun getItem() : Observable<List<RetroCrypto>> {

    val retrofit = RetroClient.getRetrofit()
    val requestInterface = retrofit.create(GetData::class.java)

    myCompositeDisposable.add(requestInterface.getData()
        // Send the Observable’s notifications to the main UI thread
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        // Subscribe to the Observer away from the main UI thread
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .map { return it }

    )
}
```

}

**getRetrofit** is the method that build the retrofit instance.

I don't know why above code generates the error.

The error is

```
1. Return is not allowed here

2. Type mismatch. Required : Observable<List<RetroCrypto>> , Found : List<RetroCrypto>
```

How can I fix the code?

Comment: You can use `.flatMap()` or `.concatMap()` instead `.map()`

Comment: Thank you for answering!
I used .flatMap() before. However, "Retrun is not allowed here" was still generated.

Comment: This is the code that I did before.

.flatMap { return Observable.just(it) }

Answer (score 0):

Inside `map`'s lambda you get the element inside the `Observable`, so in your case `it` appears to be `List<RetroCrypto>`.
If you want to return the `Observable` you have to do something like this:

```
object RemoteDataSource : DataSource {

    private val myCompositeDisposable by lazy { CompositeDisposable() }

    override fun getItem(): Observable<List<RetroCrypto>> {

        val retrofit = RetroClient.getRetrofit()
        val requestInterface = retrofit.create(GetData::class.java)

        val observable = requestInterface.getData()
                // Send the Observable’s notifications to the main UI thread
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                // Subscribe to the Observer away from the main UI thread
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())

        return observable
    }
}
```

Note: you get a disposable to add to `myCompositeDisposable` only after you subscribe, so you will have to do `myCompositeDisposable.add` outside of this function.

Comment: In this case, I think that observeOn isn't needed in getItem() method. Because I will have to do myCompositeDisposable.add outside of this function, and then define the observeOn().
Is it correct??

Comment: You can do `observeOn` and `subscribeOn` wherever you want. From a code-structure point of view it probably is better to do it outside of the `getItem()` function

Comment: Ok. I understand it. Thank you!